# Search any value in MongoDB using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, json, mongodb, mongoose

I'm very new to MongoDB and regex so please bear with me. The MongoDB documentation has an example for searching with regular expressions:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_regex

However, it only shows how to search the values of predetermined keys. 
I'm unsure how to write a query to search all values in a collection, if anyone can point it out that would be great.

Comment: If that is not possible by Mongodb syntax, what about first getting the list of all potential fields, then building the search query and running it. Why not try that?

Comment: In that case your suggestion  seems to be the only option. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not that fluent with Mongodb, however, until some Mongodb crack finds your question I would try some alternative paths in the meantime and probably updage the question if you find new additions (you can even answer your own question if you like). I can imagine that this question is of some common use.

Comment: It would be unwise to attempt to search all fields via any query operator, @hakre is correct that MongoDB does not support a match operator for field names (for good reasons) so as suggested, I would get a list of the fields you wish to search and make a regex on them. Alternatives are JS based and I would not recommend getting into that for this

Comment: @styke -- could you add some more detail about the structure of the documents and why you want to run a regex on each value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't care about size of DB (or performance), you could potentially use a [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/) function to de-normalize the data into a structure which is more easily searched. But, this will significantly increase the size of the DB as you'll duplicate all data for the collection.

Pseudo-code:

```
// recursive
// building a full property path
for(var key in obj) {
    emit(this._id, { orig: obj[key], src: path + "." + key });
    // recursive call emitChildren(path, key)
}
```

Depending on the complexity of the data, it could be reasonable.

Or, you might be able to use [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_where) to do a regex on each key/value of all documents (as you can execute arbitrary JavaScript when using $where).

No option is going to perform well (even a built in option) nor play to the strengths of mongoDB if you're running a regular expression on every value in every document in a collection.

Comment: MR is of course a bad idea here due to the weight of it, a `$where` could work if only the JS enigne had con-currency features. As you stated it would not be peformant but it would work. Without the con-currency features however, it would not due to the call needs of this query most likely.

Comment: $where could work -- it just could limit scalability potentially depending on usage scenarios ([details](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-kind-of-concurrency-does-mongodb-provide-for-javascript-operations)).

Comment: Well the main problem is that the user wants to use this to search the table fields dynamically, that means the `$where` would most likely be the only clause in the query. Of course a `$where` does not use an index and can slow querying by upto 10x and takes a JS lock which won't break for other queries as such if this were to be done on a sizeable table it will not just take scalability but any sort of real time behaviour that querying normally gives.

Comment: You have also got to consider that since this is a PHP question this query will probably sit on a web page for other users so the usage scenario here is not a good one. Imagine even 5 concurrent users to this page, they would have to wait until each predecessor users query has completed until they get a response. I mean I could be wrong on that assumption and it could be a once run command but it doesn't sound like it, it sounds like he is looking for a key-value store really.

Comment: He's also tagged it with mongoose? :) I asked a clarification question above. What you said is true if that's how it is being used, and it's hard to provide a decent answer without more details.